# How to enable usb debugging mode?

Tags: android, adb, forgot-password, usb-debugging

I forgot my mobile pattern and now i wanna recover without factory reset of my device. 
The developer options is turned off and I cannot turn on usb debugging as well.
How do I enable usb debugging and remove my pattern?
I cant even run adb commands, because when i run adb devices I don't see any devices listed there.

Comment: Question is more relevant at https://android.stackexchange.com/ have you searched there? https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=forgot+pattern+lock

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, for security reasons - if it were possible, someone who had stolen your phone would be able to unlock it as well.

Answer (score 1):

FYI cannot enable usb debugging since device will not be connected with the pc.hence, adb command wont work if usb debugging is off. Although you can disable it using

" adb  shell settings put global adb_enabled 0 "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Upon googling though, I found a link. I am not sure if it works but you can give it a shot.

https://technastic.com/usb-debugging-using-adb-command/

Please note that debugging must be enabled on your phone so that ADB can detect and communicate with it.

You can disable Developer options and USB debugging using the following commands respectively.

```
settings put global adb_enabled 0

settings put global development_settings_enabled 0
```

Try them and share if they work for you.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a link](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/).

I.e. go to About Phone in settings and tap the build number seven times.

Comment: I cant do that because after tapping 7 times on build number, it asks for pattern to confirm, and i dont remember the pattern .